# How could I set a loop in a AudioBufferSourceNode to exact match specific offset in a the underlying buffer?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

When creating a sound with AudioBufferSourceNode I can set the offset and the duration in seconds.

I have the offset and duration in sample positions which I suppose I have to convert to time, and I don't know where to start. Is it possible to get an exact match?

There seems there was sample offset and length in an earlier version of web-api but no more.

From the documentation: ([w3c](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioBuffer))

> Please note that as a low-level implementation detail, the AudioBuffer
>   is at a specific sample-rate (usually the same as the AudioContext
>   sample-rate), and that the loop times (in seconds) must be converted
>   to the appropriate sample-frame positions in the buffer according to
>   this sample-rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the match should be exact, just divide your sample-position by the sample-rate,

`second_offset = sample_offset / sample_rate`

and

`second_duration = sample_duration / sample_rate`

Comment: Thanks, so simple, I'll test and see how it turnes out.

Comment: Works like a charm as far as I have tested it! Thanks!